# is there a sleep() workaround for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

So that I could use a loop, and have it pause, say 250 ms after each iteration?  [ without setTimeout or setInterval?]

Edit:  Ok, so I have a for loop that uses AJAX to post data (**$.ajax()**) . It has lots of vars in it, like **data: 'uid=' + *uid*, + '&othervars=' + *morevars*** etc, and **each loop, the variables change**.. so If put that [huge] part into a function() {} [Inside of a setTimeout(), using a counter in the loop to increment the timeout], when it executes, will the *actual value* be in place where I put the vars?

Comment: You can create your own sleep() subroutine that takes care of all those details for you, and you could even support a parameter (I suggest making it _optional_ and default to 1 second if no parameter was provided).

Comment: How? I don't know what subroutine is

Comment: Lots of results here on SO already: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+sleep

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sleep in javascript - no setTimeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484321/sleep-in-javascript-no-settimeout)

Comment: why don't you want to use setTimeout or setInterval?

Comment: @Matt, because the code I've written would be a lot easier if I could just add one line [in the loop]: sleep(1000);

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Current browser implementations are essentially single-threaded, so sleeping in your code will likely block the entire UI. It's not what you want, and just plain isn't how JS works. Refactor your code so that you can use setTimeout.

Comment: ... or event handlers. It's tempting to add a sleep just to let the DOM finish loading ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use one of javascript's timer functions (`setTimeout` or `setInterval`).

There is no real way around them.