# Trigger certain event after timeout

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-slate

I am working on a slate application. For a slate event, I want to trigger event after 5 seconds but using setTimeout does not work, as it escapes that and returns undefined, and proceed to next step without waiting for set time out.

[I tried this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Usxew.png)

Comment: To clarify, are you saying that Slate itself comments out your setTimeout code in lines 11-13 in your screenshot?

Comment: No, I commented it out because it was not working. I tried using setTimeout to so event can wait before updating variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:** You can now use [promises in Slate functions](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/announcements/2023-10/index.html#app-building--slate).

I'm going to interpret that screenshot as meaning "lines 5-9 should ideally be between lines 11 and 13". Let me know if that's an incorrect assumption.

With that assumption in mind, I don't think that code will ever do what you want it to do. I am pretty sure, though not 100% certain, that the code run in Slate based on an Event trigger is synchronous -- it will run immediately and you can't `.then()` or `await` anything before passing the return value to the Action.

If you really just want a 5s delay, there may be a way to accomplish this by (1) an event trigger that causes a [Function](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/slate/concepts-foundry-functions/index.html) to run (this function would sleep for 5s), and (2) another event trigger that waits for that Function to complete successfully before executing the Action you actually want to run after the 5s delay. Since you [can't use libraries that depend on the Node runtime in Functions](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/functions/add-dependencies/index.html#add-npm-dependencies), I think you'll need to make your own version of `setTimeout()` -- perhaps [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484321/sleep-in-javascript-no-settimeout) but please do your own research if you go this route.

An all-Slate option might be to leverage the Code Sandbox widget to contain a function with `setTimeout()` that gets called when you pass a message into the sandbox, and which passes a message back to Slate when it completes, which in turn triggers some Action.

This really does raise the question of why you need to insert a delay here...Is it to allow some other process to complete? If yes, then could you just hook into that process directly so that whatever action you care about runs when it finishes? Could you do the processing in Functions entirely perhaps so you can use Promises? I'm not sure what might be most appropriate for your situation, but it feels like there may potentially be a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Not saying those are good solutions, but those are working solution:

- CodeSandbox's custom JS to write standard "sleep" and use the inbound/outbound events to propagate to the rest of Slate
- Use a postgres query `SELECT pg_sleep({{w_sleep_time_slider.from}});` if you have such source in the Query tab, like "Foundry Sync".
- Use a Toast timeout (`toast.open` + `toast.didClose` events)
- Calling a Function On Object technically works, but is an anti-pattern as you will waste backend resources.

The real question is indeed "Why do you need to sleep" in the first place, which might unlock other additional answers.